# How to number the definitions and theorems separately?

Tags: numbering

This is the syntax that I have written but in this syntax definitions, theorem, note, remark are numbered continuously like definition 1, theorem 2, theorem 3, note 4 and so on. But I need to number the definitions theorems separately like definition 1, definition 2, theorem 1, theorem 2 and so on. What should I change in the following syntax to number them separately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[
%top    = 2.75cm,
%bottom = 2.50cm,
%left   = 3.00cm,
%right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=in]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[]
\newtheorem{illustration}[thm]{Illustration}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pp}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ppty}[thm]{Property}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{result}[thm]{Result}
\newtheorem{note}[thm]{Note}
\newtheorem{obs}[thm]{Observation}
\newtheorem{case}[thm]{case}
\newtheorem{subcase}[thm]{subcase}
\newtheorem{Prop}[thm]{Proposotion}
\newtheorem{property}[thm]{property}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\newcommand{\NI}{\noindent}
```

Comment: Remove `[thm]`: `\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}`

Comment: separate numbering is the default. You are forcing them to be the same by using `[thm]` in all the other declarations which means use the same `thm` counter.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.